# Programmatically generate a Google Meet link

Tags: google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I'm looking to start a Google Meet meeting by calling an API that returns the new meeting URL.

It looks like this may be possible if I create a new meeting using the calendar API, but it'd be nice if that wasn't necessary.

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: Never did, nope.

Comment: Hey @codebits still no luck? I was thinking that since there is no API i might use pupeteer, however the 2FA will be a pain to handle

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61216047/is-there-direct-api-for-google-meet