# Is there direct API for Google Meet?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I'm creating a system where I want to generate Google Meet meeting from NodeJS code. Is there API for creating a new meeting in Google Meet ? There is button `Create new meeting`  on https://meet.google.com/ and I want to do something similar using API
I know that it is possible to create meeting using Google Calendar API but I'm looking for direct API for Google Meet without creating calendar event.

[EDIT]
It does not solve my problem, but maybe would help someone else. There is also option to generate meeting using [https://meet.google.com/lookup/[custom-meeting-name]](https://meet.google.com/lookup/%5Bcustom-meeting-name%5D) but you need to have Google Workspace (former GSuite)

Comment: Hi shark it is not possible to use direct API. 
We have a app working same like google meets. PM me if you need any assistance

Comment: There certainly is a Google Meet API, but only Google developers can use it. If Google was following the same "eat your own dogfood" principles as other major IT companies are, we would have access to the API.

Comment: So it is not possible to integrate the google meet in an android application right?

Comment: MenukZ how do we contact you?

Answer (score 28):

It is now possible to create a new meet by going to this url: http://meet.google.com/new

That being said, it's not immediately obvious how you could get the link for the generated meet.

Comment: It's strange that Google has this blocked off... My team uses G Suite to power our business and I was trying to find a way to quickly create a meeting over slack using a `/` command. Since there is heavy competition with competing softwares (zoom), I am surprised Google hasn't at least opened up basic API access to do things that would save me so much time. Like creating a meeting on the spot.

Comment: @LewisMenelaws the exact same need brought me here. Disappointed that there's no alternative to `/zoom` for Google Meet.

Comment: One thing people might be able to do, is make a bot that makes google events, that have a meet link, grab the event link, and then delete the event. It's definitely possible to do this, (I did this in a small side-project here: https://beer-cart.io/, repo: https://github.com/chtinahow/beer-cart.io/blob/master/src/components/GoogleAPI/createNewHangoutLink.js#L35-L56 )

Comment: There is, but it's called `/hangout`

Answer (score 26):

Try http://g.co/meet/yourmeetingname. This redirects to the same meeting URL if they're on the same Google Apps account.

Found this at https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2020/03/hangouts-meet-edu-updates.html

Comment: How it helps me to create new meeting?

Comment: This is amazing, thanks! It doesn't work for my personal Gmail, only my company  Google Apps account, but that's the only place I want it.

Comment: Another URL is `https://meet.google.com/lookup/yourmeetingname`. To avoid the invalid meeting code page you can use `https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser/signinchooser?continue=https://g.co/meet/yourmeetingname` so that the user is prompted to login and choose the correct account.

Comment: For presenting you can use g.co/present/yourmeetingname which is the same as https://meet.google.com/present/lookup/yourmeetingname

Answer (score 20):

There is currently no direct API for Google Meet

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/hangouts-meet-now-available-in-google -- does this apply to the current Google Meet (2020)?

Answer (score 18):

This is a bit of a hack, but you can create a new meeting using the Google Calendar API.

API Documentation: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events?hl=en_US

Google blog post (when Meet was Hangouts Meet): https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/hangouts-meet-now-available-in-google

In the request you can configure the conference details (i.e. Google Meet settings) and retrieve a meeting ID.

The only caveat, which is a big one, is the new Google Meet will be tied to the calendar that the API is authenticated against. Depending on who you want the meeting to be available to you'll probably have to play around with the permissions some.

Comment: As I mentioned in question I know this solution :)

Answer (score 15):

#### Vote on the feature request

There is a feature request for a Google Meet API here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/157261118

It specifically is asking for a way to get participant information of meetings in real-time. Though it is the closest thing to a Meet API that I have seen on the Issue Tracker.

Go and give it a ☆ if you want! That way Google knows its something that people are interested, at the moment it only has one.

<sup>*Please don't comment with "+1" ...  just click the star icon*</sup>

Answer (score 13):

there is no direct api for google meet for now, but through the help of the google calendar api I have created a npm package that can be used to create meeting directly it gives you the google meeting links instantly.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-meet-api

Comment: Is there a way to allow users to join before host?

Comment: Hi kashish, All users, including those in the same domain as the host, must knock to request to join the meeting unless they're on the calendar invite.  So for calendar invitation we need to create an event in google calendar of each user and for that we need auth details of each user.

Answer (score 4):

For your specific purpose of **creating a Google Meet** meeting with an API call without using the Google Calendar API I am afraid there is no other Google API service to achieve this at the moment of this answer.

Comment: Thank you but it's not Google Meet. Its hangouts and chat API

Answer (score 4):

add
"conferenceData": {
"createRequest": {
"requestId": "7qxalsvy0e"
}
},

inside your events while creating an event using google calendar API v3
a google meet link will automatically be created

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's part of the Google Calendar API and you can find it here:

https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events#conferencing

Comment: Please read question carefully. `I know that it is possible to create meeting using Google Calendar API but I'm looking for direct API`

Comment: This contents at [this Link ][1] might be what you are looking for

  [1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-meet-api