# Chatbot in Google Meet virtual conference chat

Tags: chatbot, google-hangouts

I have already to successfully created a simple chatbot following the guide:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/chat-apps-script/#0

and using it in Hangouts Chat (https://chat.google.com/).

Is there any way to add the same bot to the internal chat of a Google Meet web conference?

Answer (score 1):

Currently is not possible to achieve this because there isn't any Google Meet API.

The only Google Meet related topic that you can achieve is with the Calendar API (and is for creating events meetings):

Hangouts Meet now available in the Google Calendar API: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/hangouts-meet-now-available-in-google

Also a similar question was answered here: [Is there direct API for Google Meet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61216047/is-there-direct-api-for-google-meet)