# Is there a Google Meet API Developer document?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am curious that is there a RestAPI developer document available for Google Meet.
If yes please help me by sharing the developer document link.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic please see number **4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there direct API for Google Meet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61216047/is-there-direct-api-for-google-meet)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a public API for Google Meet, only for Google Chat.

---

#### References:

- [Google Chat API](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Calendar API to create events that use Google Meet, it gives you very limited control over the meeting itself.