# How to integrate google meet in android studio

Tags: android, videocall

I am not getting any referance to add google meet in my android app for schedule meetings through app like zoom provided its sdk's

Comment: Check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61216047/is-there-direct-api-for-google-meet

Answer (score 4):

There is no SDK for Google Meet. You can not integrate it in your android application.